# how to iterate through multiple values in file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file containing values in the following format

```
a.value1 a.value2
b.value1 b.value2
c.value1 c.value2
d.value1 d.value2
e.value1 e.value2
f.value1 f.value2
.
.
.
.
.
```

I need to run a script with the syntax `script.py value1 value2` while value1 and value2 are to be retrieved from each line of the file. How do I write a bash script to achieve this?

Comment: Why is this tagged with python? You have a python file that you want to run via bash, but you haven't shown the contents of `script.py`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, it's unclear what target language you have and what your problems are. Generally, this is very basic file reading and parsing, so the basics for that should be covered by any tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
while read a b; do
    script.py ${a#?.} ${b#?.}
done < file.txt
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop that only reads the first line of the file.

Comment: [Now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53468635/revisions) it works as expected :)